# Descendant not seeing clone() due to access privilige violation?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, clone

When i implement `Cloneable` in a class, say class `AA`, 
class `AA` is cloneable-- i can invoke `clone()` on an object of it 
without getting a `CloneNotSupportedException`. i can do this
without overriding `clone()` 
(although it is recommended in order to keep the object independent from its clone).

When a class is `Cloneable`, so are its descendants.

In the following code,

```
class ZZ {protected void mm(){System.out.println("+++");}}

class AA extends ZZ implements Cloneable {    
    // ...
    protected Object clone () throws CloneNotSupportedException {return super.clone();}
    AA cloneMe() throws CloneNotSupportedException { return (AA)clone(); }
}

class C extends AA  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        C c = new C();        
        AA a = new AA(); 
        AA a22 = (AA)(c.clone());   
        AA a3 = a.cloneMe();   
        C c2 = (C)c.clone();  

        AA a21 = (AA)a.clone();   
        a.mm();
    }
}
```

i'm getting a checked error that

```
clone() has protected access in Object
```

to the line

```
    AA a21 = (AA)a.clone();
```

when i comment the implementation of `clone()` in `AA`, i.e., the line

```
   // protected Object clone () throws CloneNotSupportedException {return super.clone();}
```

Since `AA` is cloneable, i should be able to clone an instance of it without implementing `clone()` in `AA` itself. `AA` is inheriting `clone()` from `Object`.

So - how come this error???

TIA.

//=======================================

**EDIT:**

I have the same issue with the code above except class `ZZ` which is the following code:

```
class AA implements Cloneable {    
    // ...
    // protected Object clone () throws CloneNotSupportedException {return super.clone();}
    AA cloneMe() throws CloneNotSupportedException { return (AA)clone(); }
}

class C extends AA  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        C c = new C();        
        AA a = new AA(); 
        AA a22 = (AA)(c.clone());   
        AA a3 = a.cloneMe();   
        C c2 = (C)c.clone();  

        AA a21 = (AA)a.clone();   

    }
}
```

class `ZZ` was there to show that the invocation of a `protected` method by a "grandchild" doesn't give the same error as the one by an invocation of `clone()` in a similar way.

//===============================================

**EDIT-2:**

The answer in [super.clone() operation not works in Derived Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065085/super-clone-operation-not-works-in-derived-class?rq=1) says

```
"Clone is one of the early designs in java and it has flaws".
```

this seems to be the only explanation. looking for further verification on this.

i've looked into this before and without success-- some more on the native methods than their explanations in the Java docs. Still-- is there **any** more to the internals of `clone()`-- 
how it is implemented, how it clones the members etc as well as how it is "managing" this out-of-the-ordinary access privilege? and under the circumstances??

Comment: [I get no such error.](http://ideone.com/LsDp1S)

Comment: The root cause here seems to be a misunderstanding of the `protected` access modifier. If your question is about how `clone()` is natively implemented, please rephrase your question or open a new one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: All uses of `protected` methods are from classes that have access to the methods, at least in the code shown.

Comment: @user2357112 No, `C` does not have access to `AA`'s `clone` on an `AA` reference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Huh. You seem to be right, according to the JLS, but neither Ideone nor my own copy of Eclipse have a problem with it. Dunno why.

Comment: @user2357112 Because your classes may be in the same package, at which point they are dealt with differently as rules of default access precede `protected`.

Comment: Ah, of course! I copy-pasted the example into a single file, but the questioner's real code wouldn't be structured like that.

Comment: @user2357112 Also note that OP gets the error when they comment out the overriden `clone` method in `AA` (which is in the same package).

Comment: Effective Java Second Edition warns you about clone in "Item 11: Override `clone` judiciously".  It recommends using a copy constructor or (static) copy factory instead.  Note that you'd have to write these manually... but you're already doing that if you're writing your own clone method.

Comment: @Powerlord thx for a useful comment at last. will look at the Item although it didn't show an indication of an answer to this at first glance.